# What is the best way to install windows on a rhel 6 machine?

Tags: windows-7, installation, rhel-6

I have a rhel6 machine in my office. I wanted to install windows 7 on that. My idea was to install a dual booting, however my system admin seems uncomfortable with that. He asked me to install a virtual box kind of software, on which he will install windows 7. I need to access my files from both windows and rhel6. In this scenario,I have two questions :

1. In terms of system performance, is dual booting a better option than virtual box kind of softwares to host two operating systems on a system? (If that is the case, I will plead with my system admin a little more)
2. If I go with virtual box softwares, which one will be best for rhel6?

My hardware specs are: i7 2 Ghz, 8 gb ram, 320 gb hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can use Oracle Virtual Box.  It's free and it works for what you are asking.  If you already have a license you can use VMware Workstation.  That is not free.

Some people like VB other's like VMworkstation.  I would go the route of a virtual machine before dual booting.  That way you can see if it fits your needs with minimal impact.

I currenlty have two laptops, one with linux as the Host OS and Windows as a VM through Virtual Box.  The other laptop has Win7 as the Host OS and about 6 linux VMs through VMWorkstation.  They both do the job that I need.

You will get access to your files with either solution.

The virtual route is essentially sharing your computer's resources e.g. memory, proc, HD with another computer, but in a separate environment.  It's like running two computers at once on the same hardware.